# iPhone webapp icon

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications

I want to create an icon on an iPhone to link to a web app, but assuming my users won't know to find "add to home" I think it's better to have an html link saying "**click here to add an icon to your desktop**" (or something along those lines).
I know the code for the icon is

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

But what's the code for the "click here"?

Thanks!...any time you help me you save a kitten!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to add a bookmark to home screen by code, you have to indicate to your users that they need to do it manually.

To do this, there is a neat little JS library: [mobile-bookmark-bubble](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/).

> The Mobile Bookmark Bubble is a JavaScript library that adds a promo
>   bubble to the bottom of your mobile web application, inviting users to
>   bookmark the app to their device's home screen. The library uses HTML5
>   local storage to track whether the promo has been displayed already,
>   to avoid constantly nagging users.
>
> The current implementation of this library specifically targets Mobile
>   Safari, the web browser used on iPhone and iPad devices.

Comment: Awesome!...Is there anything similar for Android (or, ugh, dare I say, Blackberry)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code for the 'click here' yourself, it's not a standard part of the operating system or anything. It's just HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: That depends on what you want it to look like. Take a look at an existing implementation if you're curious.